# How to calculate total power required for an electric vehicle (e-bike) design?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

I wanted to design an ebike with good enough specs to satisfy my requirements, my first consideration was the power required to move the bike at my required speed and from there I can choose a motor.

I started by setting the max speed, max total weight (rider + bike), and acceleration :

Top speed: 50 km/h, 13.88 m/s

Max Weight: 200 kg, 1,974 N

Acceleration: 0-50 km/h in 30 sec, ~ 0.5 m/s^2

Then what forces to consider:

1. drag
2. friction
3. force required to reach the required speed.
4. As the force required to overcome inclination of the ground is regained, I decided to neglect it.

To calculate each one I used rough conditions and here is how I calculated each one of the forces:

F1:

```
Equation : ( (air density) (wind resistance coefficient) (Area) (wind velocity)^2 ) / 2

1. air density: 1 kg/m^3
2. coefficient: ~ 1
3. Area: ~ 0.5 m^2
4. (wind velocity)^2 : average 15 km/h + max speed = 65 km/h, ~ (18)^2 = 324 m/s

Total = 81 N
```

F2:

```
Equation: (coefficient of rolling resistance) (mg) 
1- coefficient: ~ 0.01
2- mg: 1,974 N

Total = 19.74 N
```

F3:

```
Equation: ma
1- ma : 100 N

Total = 100 N
```

Ftotal = 200.74 N

Ptotal = Ftotal * Velocity = 2,786.27 Watts, ~ 3.75HP

Here is where I stalled, I think this power is the power required to move from rest to the required velocity, then the momentum will keep the bike moving and the power it will consume would be the power required to overcome friction and drag, which is around 1.4 kw.

What did I miss and is there a flaw in these calculations?

1400 watts to maintain my speed sounds a lot to me and what does the total power of 2,786 watts mean in watts per hour and what motor power does all these calculations translate to.

Where does Work and K.E. Fit into these calculations, if relevant?

P.S. I know that there are inefficiencies in the bike, the motor,and in energy getting lost converting from electrical energy to mechanical energy, but it can be considered later.

Edit : I don't think the question would fit in the engineering category, I will post it in electrical engineering, but please suggest the appropriate category, thanks for taking the time to read.